# Unable to verify leaf signature npm

Tags: javascript, express, npm

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');                       
const app = express();


app.get("/" , function(req, res) {
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bhubaneswar&appid=5b1ee8df0720f3eca886c9ca1cb03385&units=metric";

  https.get(url, function(request, response){
    console.log(response);
  });

  res.send("Server is up & running");
});

app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running at port 5000");
});
```

[Nodemon app getting crashed][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rka1M.jpg

When ever am running the nodemon, error is arising as UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE. Even tried several ways provided bu Stack Overflow & GitHub. Still none of them worked out.